# ResizableArray based queue implementation

Tags: java, queue

I am implementing basic data structures in Java. I have written this simple resizing array queue implementation and looking for ways to simplify the implementation as it looks like I am using too many variables which can be reduced. I would appreciate any ideas to make it simpler, implementation advice and constructive criticisms.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ResizingArrayQueue<T> implements Iterable<T>{
    private T[] mQueue;
    private int mHead, mTail, mCurrentSize, mSize;

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new QueueIterator();
    }

    public ResizingArrayQueue() { 
        mQueue = (T[]) new Object[1];
        mHead = 0;
        mSize = 1;
        mTail = mSize - 1;
        mCurrentSize = 0;
    }

    public void enQueue(T valueToEnque){
        if (mCurrentSize == mSize) {
            resize(2 * mSize);
        }
        mTail = ++mTail % mSize;
        mQueue[mTail] = valueToEnque;
        mCurrentSize++;
    }

    public T deQueue(){
        if(mCurrentSize == mSize / 4) {
            resize(mSize / 2);
        }
        T value = mQueue[mHead % mSize];
        mQueue[mHead % mSize] = null;
        mHead++;
        mCurrentSize--;
        return value;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return mCurrentSize == 0;
    }

    public void resize(int size){
        T[] newQueue = (T[]) new Object[size];
        int mCurrent = 0;
        while(mCurrent < mCurrentSize){
            newQueue[mCurrent] = mQueue[(mCurrent + mHead) % mSize];
            mCurrent++;
        }

        mQueue = newQueue;
        mSize = size;
        mHead = 0;
        mTail = mCurrentSize - 1; 
    }

    private class QueueIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        private int mCurrent = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return mCurrent < mCurrentSize;
        }

        public T next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            T valueToReturn = mQueue[(mCurrent + mHead) % mSize];
            mCurrent++;
            return valueToReturn;
        }

        public void remove(){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     private T[] mQueue;
>     private int mHead, mTail, mCurrentSize, mSize;
> ```

The value that you are storing in `mSize` is available as `mQueue.length`.

```
    private T[] mQueue = (T[]) new Object[1];
    private int mHead = 0;
    private int mSize = 0;
```

But if you get rid of `mSize`, then there is no reason to differentiate `mCurrentSize`.  So just call that `mSize`.

You also don't need `mTail`, as `mHead`, `mSize`, and `mQueue.length` determine `mTail` uniquely.

You don't need a constructor, as you can initialize these values without further calculation.

> ```
>         T[] newQueue = (T[]) new Object[size];
>         int mCurrent = 0;
>         while(mCurrent < mCurrentSize){
>             newQueue[mCurrent] = mQueue[(mCurrent + mHead) % mSize];
>             mCurrent++;
>         }
>
>         mQueue = newQueue;
>         mSize = size;
>         mHead = 0;
>         mTail = mCurrentSize - 1;
> ```

There's a built-in for this.

```
        mQueue = Arrays.copyOfRange(mQueue, mHead, mHead + size);
        mHead = 0;
```

Now you don't `newQueue` or `mCurrent`.

As previously said, you don't need `mSize` or `mTail`.

> ```
>     public void enQueue(T valueToEnque){
>         if (mCurrentSize == mSize) {
>             resize(2 * mSize);
>         }
>         mTail = ++mTail % mSize;
>         mQueue[mTail] = valueToEnque;
>         mCurrentSize++;
>     }
>
>     public T deQueue(){
>         if(mCurrentSize == mSize / 4) {
>             resize(mSize / 2);
>         }
>         T value = mQueue[mHead % mSize];
>         mQueue[mHead % mSize] = null;
>         mHead++;
>         mCurrentSize--;
>         return value;
>     }
> ```

To implement, you could do it like

```
    public void enQueue(T valueToEnque) {
        if (mSize >= mQueue.length) {
            resize(2 * mQueue.length);
        }

        mQueue[(mHead + mSize) % mQueue.length] = valueToEnque;
        mSize++;
    }

    public T deQueue() {
        if (mSize <= mQueue.length / 4) {
            resize(mQueue.length / 2);
        }

        T value = mQueue[mHead];
        mQueue[mHead] = null;
        mHead = ++mHead % mQueue.length;
        mSize--;

        return value;
    }
```

By using `<=` or `>=` rather than strict equality, we can catch situations where the size jumped over the gating.  For example, if you implemented `QueueIterator.remove` without calling `deQueue`, you might find that you had skipped over the `resize` check.

See how we determine the value that would have been held in `mTail` as needed rather than maintaining it.

Notice how things are easier if we maintain `mHead` as the actual index rather than allowing it to grow unbounded.  Note that this also avoids integer overflow in an edge case (if you never resize, `mHead` always grows).